# javascript/Jquery Accordion is not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have problems with jquery accordion. It seems quite tricky.

The first accordion, project1, is working great (thanks to [Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver)) but 2nd & 3rd an so on does not work. I do not really know if I should use `.filter`.

Here is the code & example page: http://jsfiddle.net/THjgV/2/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they all have different heights, you need to store and use each height independently, I suggest using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) and [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for this.  Also change your IDs to classes as they should be unique.

```
$('.slickbox').hide().each(function() {
    $.data(this, 'height', $(this).height());
});
$('.more a').toggle(function() {
    var sb = $(this).parent().prev('.slickbox').slideDown(3200);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: '+=' + sb.data('height')
    }, 3200);
    return false;
}, function() {
    var sb = $(this).parent().prev('.slickbox').slideUp(3200);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: '-=' + sb.data('height')
    }, 3200);
    return false;
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/T6K4p/), this loops through and stores the heights of each `.slickbox` (now using a class!) and stores it.  When each link is clicked it's specifically toggling the `class="slickbox"` element that precedes it, and uses it's stored `'height'` value for scrolling.

Comment: Damn man! You have made my day :) Thanks again! 

PS: You have taught me Jquery accordion behavior today. Thanks